# Given $a_1=6$ and that $a_{n+1}=\frac{(a_n+1/a_n)}{2}$ how do I prove $a_n \ge 1$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

My final goal is to prove that $\lim _{n \to \infty }a_n=1$

However trying to prove that I realised I must first prove:

$a_{n+1} < a_{n}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

And to prove that I would have to prove that:

$a_{n} \ge 1$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I am now a bit lost, I would like an insight to how I could prove it the way I am currently trying to (with the two sub-proofs), or otherwise an intuition to how I could prove it differently.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: Subtract $1$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First convince yourself that $a_n >0$ for all $n$.

Then observe that $x+\frac 1 x \ge 2$ for any positive number $x$ because $(x-1)^{2} \ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I hope you have a beautiful day.

Comment: Aggressively clean answer +1

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n\gt0$, then
$$
\frac{a_n+\frac1{a_n}}2-1=\frac{(a_n-1)^2}{2a_n}\ge0
$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer was already provided by @geetha290krm, this is just a slightly different perspective. You want to know if the positive solution of the equation $x = \frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac 1x \right)$ can be approximated using the fixed point method, using the initial guess $a_0 = 6$. Using the fixed point theorem you can show that this is so, and you can even show that the same result holds for any $a_0 > 0$. To reach this conclusion you just need to note that $g([1, +\infty])\subseteq [1,+\infty[$ and that $|g'|<1$ on that interval. The case $a_0 \in (0,1)$ is also covered because $g(a_0) >1$ and we fall in the previous situation.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain, but I did not understand. Could you possibly. What's g?

Comment: @Sover Sorry, $g(x)=\frac 12 (x+\frac 1x)$. the fixed point method is all about solving equations in the form $g(x)=x$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Monotone Convergence Theorem and the Wavy Curve method to see the convergence.

Note that $a_{n+1}  - a_n = -\frac{(1+a_n)(a_n-1)}{2a_n}$. Then possible limit points are $1$ and $-1$.

Then, By wavy curve if you plot it on real line then you will observe that for $a_1 =6$ . It is Monotonically decreasing and bounded below by 1. So, by Monotone Convergence Theorem, $a_n$ converges to 1.